# Rendering template from another controller causes NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I'm working on a rails app that contains a Users controller and an Images controller. This is the create method in the Images controller:

```
def create
  @image = current_user.images.build(image_params)
  if @image.save
    flash[:success] = "Image uploaded!"
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render 'users/show'   #Error occurs here
  end
end
```

Successful saves are handled fine, but if the image is too large or non-existent and 'users/show' is rendered, rails gives the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___2850090823537495038_37901140'
  app/controllers/images_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

I expect this happened because I hadn't initialized all the variables necessary for 'users/show' within my Images controller, so I moved the content from the show method of the Users controller to a new method in the Application controller and called it before rendering the page from Images. Here's the intitialize method:

```
def initialize_show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @images = @user.images.paginate(page: params[:page])
  @image = current_user.images.build if logged_in?
end
```

And the new create method:

```
def create
  @image = current_user.images.build(image_params)
  if @image.save
    flash[:success] = "Image uploaded!"
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    initialize_show   # Called this method
    render 'users/show'
  end
end
```

Now rails is giving the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find User with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:6:in `initialize_show'
  app/controllers/images_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

What am I missing here? This is my first rails app so I appreciate the help.

Comment: You aren't posting an `id` param to your `images#create` action, so the line `@user = User.find(params[:id])` is not successful. You should read the errors closely because they are very clear in this case. You are likely better off running `@user = current_user` or something like that if the `@user` is always just going to be the current user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ptd provided the answer in a comment above. `@user` wasn't getting initialized because the `id` param wasn't posted to `images#create`. Here's the solution:

```
  def create
    @image = current_user.images.build(image_params)
    if @image.save
      flash[:success] = "Image uploaded!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @user = current_user
      initialize_show    # I removed the @user initialization in this method
      render 'users/show'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your template (`users/show`) uses something (@vars) that is not available in this case. Can you show that template code? Maybe you have something line `@user.name` there but this var is not initialized in case you have described...